# ASP.NET MVC is not displaying the image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public static string PDFUrl(int id, int page)
        {


        }
```

Comment: What does it put in for the src attribute?

Comment: It calls a ViewDocument.aspx page from the apphelper funcion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything addition, I can only offer some suggestions:

You should be putting that imageUrl together in the controller action, and attaching that to your view data. You should have very few method invocations in your view code unless you're using the HtmlHelper.

Comment: Hey Tejs,I have added the html helper method and it in turn calls my viewdocument.aspx page.